# Unable to minimize the gap between two adjacent buttons in a Neumorphism layout

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-theme

I am currently working on a mobile application where I have implemented the Neumorphism design using the **com.github.fornewid:neumorphism:0.3.0** library.
In my layout, I have a requirement to display two buttons adjacent to each other without any visible gap between them. However, I am facing difficulty in removing or minimizing the gap between these buttons.

To provide a better understanding of the issue, I have attached a screenshot of the layout
[image]

Additionally, here is the XML code snippet for the relevant part of the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView
        android:id="@+id/start_timer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/_18sdp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:neumorph_shadowColorDark="@color/dark_shadow_dark"
        app:neumorph_shadowColorLight="@color/light_shadow_dark"
        app:neumorph_shapeAppearance="@style/NeumorphismTimerShape"
        app:neumorph_shapeType="flat"
        app:neumorph_strokeColor="@color/black"
        app:neumorph_strokeWidth="1dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/start_timer_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/timer_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timer_countdown_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/_00_00_00"
            android:textColor="@color/leaveGreen"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView>

    <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphImageView
        android:id="@+id/cancel_timer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/_18sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/timer_off_icon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:neumorph_shadowColorDark="@color/dark_shadow_dark"
        app:neumorph_shadowColorLight="@color/light_shadow_dark"
        app:neumorph_shapeAppearance="@style/NeumorphismTimerOffShape"
        app:neumorph_shapeType="flat"
        app:neumorph_strokeColor="@color/black"
        app:neumorph_strokeWidth="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Furthermore, I have defined the following styles for the Neumorphism shapes used in the buttons:

```
<style name="NeumorphismTimerShape">
    <item name="neumorph_cornerSizeBottomLeft">@dimen/_115sdp</item>
    <item name="neumorph_cornerSizeTopLeft">@dimen/_115sdp</item>
</style>

<style name="NeumorphismTimerOffShape">
    <item name="neumorph_cornerSizeBottomRight">@dimen/_115sdp</item>
    <item name="neumorph_cornerSizeTopRight">@dimen/_115sdp</item>
</style>
```

Could someone please guide me on how to achieve the desired layout with no visible gap between the adjacent buttons in the Neumorphism design? Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout, you wrap everything using `NeumorphCardView`, inside it will have things aligned horizontally using `LinearLayout`:

```xml
<soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView
    android:id="@+id/start_timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/_18sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:neumorph_shadowColorDark="@color/dark_shadow_dark"
    app:neumorph_shadowColorLight="@color/light_shadow_dark"
    app:neumorph_shapeAppearance="@style/NeumorphismTimerShape"
    app:neumorph_shapeType="flat"
    app:neumorph_strokeColor="@color/black"
    app:neumorph_strokeWidth="1dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">
        
           <ImageView
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:id="@+id/start_timer_icon"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/timer_icon" />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/timer_countdown_text"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="34dp"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:text="@string/_00_00_00"
               android:textColor="@color/leaveGreen"
               android:textSize="18sp"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cancel_timer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/_18sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/timer_off_icon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </LinearLayout>

</soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView>
```